# Cannot find name 'RTCSignalingState'

Tags: angular, webrtc, angular2-forms, rtcpeerconnection

I'm getting compile time error while connecting RTCPeerConnection.

```
/node_modules/@types/webrtc/RTCPeerConnection.d.ts (316,30): Cannot find name 'RTCSignalingState'.

const servers = null;
this.pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

I have installed npm install --save-dev @types/webrtc
is there anything new I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i fixed the issue. 
The issue is the version. 
the npm webrtc package version should be match with your typescript version.
i have used typescript version 2.0.3 and equalent version for webrtc is 0.0.21.